# How can I remove the extension of files with a specific extension?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, directory

I'm trying to create a program that would remove the extensions of files with that specific extension in a directory.

So for instance there exists a directory d1, within that directory there are three files a.jpg, b.jpg and c.txt and the extension that I want to manipulate is .jpg.

After calling my program, my output should be `a b c.txt` since all files with .jpg now have jpg removed from them.

Here is my attempt to solve it so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter an extension"
read extension
echo "Enter a directory"
read directory
allfiles=$( ls -l $directory)
for x in $allfiles
do
        ext=$( echo $x | sed 's:.*.::')
        if [ $ext -eq $extension]
        then
                echo $( $x | cut -f 2 -d '.')
        else
                echo $x
        fi

done
```

However, when I run this, I get an error saying

```
'-f' is not defined
'-f' is not defined
```

what should I change in my code?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by piping the result of `find` to a `while` loop:

```bash
# First step - basic idea:
# Note: requires hardening

find . -type f | while read file; do
    # do some work with ${file}
done
```

Next, you can extract a filename without an extension with `${file%.*}` and an extension itself with `${file##*.}` (see [Bash - Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)):

```bash
# Second step - work with file extension:
# Note: requires hardening

find . -type f | while read file; do
    [[ "${file##*.}" == "jpg" ]] && echo "${file%.*}" || echo "${file}";
done
```

The final step is to introduce some kind of hardening. Filenames may contain "strange" characters, like a new line character or a backslash. We can force `find` to print the filename followed by a null character (instead of the newline character), and then [tune `read` to be able to deal with it](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read):

```bash
# Final step

find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    [[ "${file##*.}" == "jpg" ]] && echo "${file%.*}" || echo "${file}";
done
```

Comment: so should it look something like this?
   '#!/bin/bash
    echo "Enter an extension"
    read extension
    echo "Enter a directory"
    read directory
    find . -type f | while read $directory; do
            [[ "${directory##*.}" == $extension ]] && echo "${directory}";
    done

Answer (score 0):

What about use `mv` command?

```
mv a.jpg a
```